# Why does TypeScript not handle booleans stored in variables?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, boolean

Consider these two code snippets:

```
if(!requiredProp) {
  return null;
}

return <Component requiredProp={requiredProp} />
```

```
const dontRenderComponent = !requiredProp
if(dontRenderComponent) {
  return null;
}

return <Component requiredProp={requiredProp} />
```

To me, they are virtually the same code.
However, in the second case, TypeScript complains that `requiredProp` is possibly `undefined`.

Why is it so, and can this be solved somehow? I wouldn't want to use the non-null assertion operator, as this may make it harder to catch other cases later on, where the required prop is actually `undefined` (when the condition changes)

TS Version: 4.0.3

Comment: Typescript cannot narrow the `requiredProp` type based on the comparison with some different variable, it is its current implementation limitation.

Comment: So, there is no way of working around this except for using a non-null assertion? IRL the conditionals I have are more complex, and I'd like to assign them to variables so as not to duplicate them all over the place.